# How to automate tokenomics research and data collection?

Tags: external-api, database, explorer-api, tokenomics

I want to create a tokenomics database.

I want to build a bot to automate data collection that answers for each token on the blockchain some of the [questions asked and answered in this article](https://every.to/almanack/tokenomics-101).

I am a total newbie when it comes to blockchain. So, I have some basic questions.

Where is this information located? How did the author discover the numbers he quotes? Is there an API one could use to collect this information? (See update.)

Update: In writing this question, I discovered [this Etherscan API](https://docs.etherscan.io/). How might one leverage that API to obtain the tokenomics data I want?

###### [Source](https://every.to/almanack/tokenomics-101) [emphasis mine]

> There will only ever be **21,000,000 bitcoin**, and they’re released at a rate that gets cut in **half every four years or so**. Roughly **19,000,000 already exist**, so there are only **2,000,000 more to be released over the next 120 years**.

> What about Ethereum? The circulating supply is around **118,000,000**, and **there’s no cap** on how many Ether can exist. But Ethereum’s net emissions were **recently adjusted via a burn mechanism** so that it would reach a **stable supply**, or potentially even be deflationary, resulting in somewhere between **100-120m tokens total**. Given that, we shouldn’t expect much inflationary pressure on Ether either. It could even be deflationary.

> Dogecoin has no supply cap either, and it is currently **inflating at around 5% per year**. So of the three, we should expect inflationary tokenomics to erode the value of Doge more than Bitcoin or Ethereum.

> The last thing you want to consider with supply is allocation. **Do a few investors hold a ton of the tokens which are going to be unlocked soon?** Did the protocol give most of its tokens to the community? How fair does the distribution seem? If a bunch of investors have 25% of the supply and those tokens will unlock in a month, you might hesitate before buying in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://coinmarketcap.com/ or https://www.coingecko.com/, they both have a pretty extensive information per token and they got a good API with historical data.